# Reputation notifications aren't shown on your profile page

Tags: discussion, bug, support

Whenever you gain reputation and you visit your profile page, usually on StackOverflow and other sites you see the reputation change in a blue square next to the word "reputation" on the reputation tab.

This isn't the case on the WP network, is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of bits are cached/only refreshed after a number of hits/visits/some other magic metric - As Stackoverflow gets a bit more traffic than this site, these caches get refreshed a lot faster.